# How to close a GitHub pull request with a commit message?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

My team uses pull requests internally for code-reviewing the application we maintain, but when it's time to merge a commit, we just push directly to `master`. We're all repo collabs anyway, and by *not* using the pull request to merge code, we avoid polluting our commit history with merge commits. Since the app is internal to our team, no one else is affected.

What I want to know is, can I amend my commit message with something like `"closes PR #30"` and have github automatically close the pull request for me?

I know you can use commit messages to close issues, so I'm hoping there is something similar for pull requests. I did a quick search online and of SO, and didn't see anything.

Comment: [This](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages) help page from GitHub might help you.

Comment: Thanks @ZeissS, but that link only addresses closing *issues*, not pull requests.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You probably want to look at this [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages).  It says:

> You can use any of the following keywords to close an issue via commit message:
>
> - close
> - closes
> - closed
> - fix
> - fixes
> - fixed
> - resolve
> - resolves
> - resolved

So "Fixes #123" or "Resolved #456" will work.  All pull requests are mapped as issues, so this will works for pull requests too.

Note: you'll see a message about unmerged commits because you amended the pull request.  So looking at the pull request, it won't be immediately obvious that the PR was incorporated (versus just plain closed) unless you put something meaningful in the first line of the commit message so you can see the message in the pull request.

Comment: "All pull requests are mapped as issues, so this will works for pull requests too." -- Ahhh, *that's* the part I was missing! How do you know that? If github could just add that as a short one-sentence addendum to the page you linked, my question would have been answered!

Comment: I tested this, and it worked! You're right about the "unmerged commits" warning, but my PR also says "skingsland closed this in <SHA1 hash with link to commit> 2 minutes ago." So anyone looking at the PR and wondering why it was closed could click on the commit hash link, and see that the commit is in `master`.

Comment: @SteveK Unfortunately, I only know that because I've been using GitHub for a while and know that pull requests show up in the issue list.  I agree, it would be helpful it GitHub mentioned it somewhere prominently. :-)

Comment: Note that the pull request will only be closed when the default branch receives the commit which closes it.  If the pull request is open against a branch that is not your defaul, this can be confusing.

Comment: I was also confused by that page saying only issues, I hope they put in there somewhere that this is also available for pull requests

Comment: Does anyone know if this is possible with GitLab as well?  I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: @Wildcard Take a look at this: http://doc.gitlab.com/ee/customization/issue_closing.html  I believe that has what you want.

Comment: @jszakmeister, thanks, but that only seems to work with *issues*, not with merge requests.

Comment: I think you mis-read it--it does refer to merge requests.  Read the first line again: "When a commit or merge request resolves one or more issues, it is possible to automatically have these issues closed when the commit or merge request lands in the project's default branch." :-)

Comment: No, I meant closing a *merge request* by referencing it in a commit message.  See feature request here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/14206

Comment: @Wildcard I see.  To be honest, I don't know what it really means to close a merge request via a commit message--the concept just feels "off" to me.  It's a bit goofy to put up a merge request, review it, and then pull it into master as a patch instead of merging it. *shrug*  I can see why it's not currently supported, but I see now what you were asking for.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister One use case I ran into: Someone who opened a PR to my project is never heard from again. I still want the change. So I copy their changes to my own branch, make some changes, and push that commit directly to my default branch. Using a commit message, I can *also* close that PR since it isn't needed anymore.