# How to trigger "Merged" status for a pull request with commit message

Tags: git, github, merge

Like some [others](http://blog.spreedly.com/2014/06/24/merge-pull-request-considered-harmful/#.VLg9D3ktGAg), I'm not fond of the default "Merge Pull Request" button behavior, so instead I get things in shape on the local command line, then push back to the repo.  I'd like for that push to automatically resolve the original PR as "Merged."

Using the magic strings specified [here](https://help.github.com/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/) (found from similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23015168/1366219)) is *almost* what I want. Unfortunately, including `closes #123` marks the PR as "Closed", which by itself is kind of synonymous with "Rejected".

I would like to know if there is a way to trigger the same "Merged" status (w/ purple icon) that you get when you just press the button.

So far I've tried adding the following to my commit messages, to no avail:

- `closes #xyz` ([just sets Closed status and associates](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/17))
- `Merge pull request #123 from user/fork` ([just associates](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/16))

Comment: Default GitHub merge message is `Merge pull request #XXX from user/branch`. Probably we need to try similar one.

Comment: Agree, though I'd like confirmation if possible. I'll try that next time if I don't get an answer by then.

Comment: I would suggest https://github.com/contact to "Contact a Human" :)

Comment: @ReedCopsey -- done.  Sergey -- didn't work :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

GitHub considers a PR "Merged" as soon as the commits in the PR branch are also found in the target branch (typically `master`). Using a `rebase` workflow, your process might look like this:

1. Create a branch tracking your PR branch: `git checkout -t origin/my-pr-branch`
2. `git rebase master`
3. `git push -f origin my-pr-branch`
   (or just `git push -f` if you've changed `push.default` to something sane)
4. Push your changes to remote and local `master`, closing the PR: `git push origin HEAD:master && git push . HEAD:master`

Comment: I assume the issue is somewhere in the rebasing / squashing since it's creating new commits which are not really connected to the original ones in the PR.

Comment: Yeah, if the PR was opened on a fork then you'll need the owner of the branch to rebase/manipulate the branch and push to his or her fork before you can do the fast-forward push to master from your machine.

Comment: This matches the response I got from GitHub customer support. Basically, there is no support at all right now for rebase-style PRs.