# Close GitLab CE Merge Requests From Commit Message

Tags: git, gitlab, pull-request, gitlab-ce

A useful feature of GitHub is that users are able to close their "pull requests" (PRs) via commit message. For instance, if `Closes #1` is written in a commit message and that commit subsequently lands on the `master` branch, GitHub will automatically close the PR.

GitLab has a similar setup, but the pull requests are known as "merge requests" (MRs). Although I have found support for the automatic-PR-closing feature in GitHub, it appears as though GitLab is completely devoid of this useful feature. The only way to close merge requests (that I've found) is by manually clicking the "Accept" or "Close" buttons on GitLab itself.

[This SO question illustrates the feature in question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23015168/how-to-close-a-github-pull-request-with-a-commit-comment)

And yes, I'm aware that you can close **issues**, as stated here: http://docs.gitlab.com/ee/customization/issue_closing.html

But as that page says:

> When a commit or merge request resolves one or more issues, it is possible to automatically have these issues closed when the commit or merge request lands in the project's default branch.

So only ***issues*** will be closed if a MR or a commit lands in `master`, but it doesn't speak to the closing of MRs if a commit lands in `master`.

I searched through the GitLab-CE repo's issues and came up empty handed. Is this just a poorly documented feature, or does GitLab CE simply not support this?

Comment: Just came across this question after wondering about the same thing myself. When adding something like `Closes !1` to the commit message, Gitlab *does* linkify the `!1`, but does not close the merge request as one might expect. So I guess the feature is simply not supported, but I'm not entirely certain – it does feel like a strange omission.

Comment: @d0gb3r7 My question is why, after avid searching, have I found no other resources on the topic (tickets on the repo, articles, nothing)? I completely forgot about this feature but perhaps it is time to submit a ticket.

Comment: Same question. And no info since 3 months passed. Closing MR with commit message is preferred, coz i'd like to merge squashing commits into 1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is an issue for GitLab CE that addresses this, but it looks like the devs are choosing to ignore it (the issue was closed without any public comment).

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/4106

Answer (score 2):

Evidently it is not supported as of GitLab version 9.1.1.

There is a GitLab CE issue **currently open** requesting that feature.  If you want it, you can log on and vote for it.

- [Close merge request with commit message](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/13268)